# Showing theorems with a given number

Tags: environments, counters

I need to write up solutions (in LaTeX) for the problems which our instructor will give throughout the course. In order to do that I created an environment called `prob` (see below). Basically, it is a word "Problem" with the corresponding number (all problems are numbered). The issue is that I want to keep all solutions in the same file, but I need to submit only the required subset of problems each week (say, problems 1-5 in the first week, 6-8 the second, etc.)

Therefore, the question is whether it is possible to somehow show only solutions of the problems with the given numbers? In other words, I need a command `showprob` such that `showprob{1}` shows (prints) the solution of the Problem 1. Perhaps, one needs to modify the environment (or use another technique).

Of course, one might create separate files for different homeworks (subsets of problems) and just use the `\input` command, but I would like to avoid this. One (probably unconvincing) reason is that I want to be able to show *any* subset of solutions (say, my friend needs only solutions of problems 1, 5 and 12, then it would convenient to send him/her only those solutions instead of bunch of files containing solutions of problems 1-16).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}

\newcounter{probnum}

\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {.}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\textnormal{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{prob}[probnum]{Problem}

\begin{document}
\prob{Solution.}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `\setcounter{probnum}{4}` will result in the next problem being 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even if it's not related to your problem, using

```
\prob{Solution}
```

is wrong under many respects. The correct syntax, with the given code, is

```
\begin{prob}
Solution
\end{prob}
```

Failure to properly using `\begin{prob}` and `\end{prob}` will end up in essentially random spacing. There is also no need to define a counter, because `\newtheorem` will do it for you.

Now, let's assume your problems are sequentially numbered, say from 1 to 8, and you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\showproblems{1-3,4,6}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 1
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 2
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 3
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 4
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 5
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 6
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 7
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 8
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

and you want that only the stated problems, that is, 1,2,3,4,6 are printed. I left out the style declaration, because it is not relevant to the solution.

The first step is to change the name of the theorem-like environment and define `prob` to do a check with the given list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {.}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\textnormal{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem*{probinner}{Problem \problemnumber}
\newcommand{\problemnumber}{}% initialize

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{+b}
 {
  \richrow_prob_body:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showproblems}{m}
 {
  \richrow_prob_list:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_richrow_prob_list_seq
\seq_new:N \l__richrow_prob_temp_seq
\int_new:N \g_richrow_prob_count_int

% populate the sequence containing the problems to show
\cs_new_protected:Nn \richrow_prob_list:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__richrow_prob_add:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__richrow_prob_add:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__richrow_prob_temp_seq { - } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__richrow_prob_temp_seq == 1 }
   {% single number
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_richrow_prob_list_seq { #1 }
   }
   {% range
    \int_step_inline:nnn
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__richrow_prob_temp_seq {1} } % start
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__richrow_prob_temp_seq {2} } % end
     { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_richrow_prob_list_seq { ##1 } }
   }
 }

% define the code for prob
\cs_new_protected:Nn \richrow_prob_body:n
 {
  % increment the counter
  \int_gincr:N \g_richrow_prob_count_int
  % define the problem number
  \cs_set:Npx \problemnumber { \int_eval:n { \g_richrow_prob_count_int } }
  % check against the list
  \seq_if_in:NxT \g_richrow_prob_list_seq { \problemnumber }
   {% the problem is in the list
    \probinner #1 \endprobinner
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\showproblems{1-3,4,6}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 1
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 2
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 3
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 4
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 5
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[Difficult]
Solution for problem 6
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 7
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
Solution for problem 8
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg for the poiting out the mistake. Your code works, but I have one more question for you: does there exist any tutorial (or at least documentation) for programming your own macros in LaTeX (like you did in the sceond part of preamble). It seem to be quite advanced but it would be interesting to learn it.